# How do I stop Tkinter window from destroy when the navigation button is clicked the second time?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter app with a main window and a secondary window. When I click the navigation button (Next Page) on the main window to move to the next page, it works fine; when I click the "Back" button to move back, it also works fine. The problem is, the next time I click the "Next Page" button on the main page, the window destroys. How do I make it such that I can move back and forth indefinitely without closing the window? Below are the codes for the two navigation buttons:

```
#the function to move to move from main to secondary page
def next_page():
    root.destroy()
    import page2 

#the function to move back from secondary to main page
def home_page():
    root.destroy()
    import page1
```

Comment: Put all of your widgets inside frames and call `<tkinter.Frame>.pack()` and `<tkinter.Frame>.pack_forget()` whenever you want to show/hide the frame.

Comment: `destroy()` is for destroing window and it should destroy it at first click.

Comment: `import` loads code only once - and it remeber it - and it will not load it again when you run it in function. You should keep code in function  i.e. `def show_page()`, inmport it only once `import page1` and run function `page1.show_page()` in `home_page`

Answer (score 1):

```
def moveToSecondWindow():
    firstScreen.withdraw()
    secondScreen.deiconify()
```

Above will hide the first screen, and show the second screen when you call this function on something like a button click.

```
firstScreen = Tk()
firstScreen.title("1st Tkinter window")

secondScreen = Tk()
secondScreen.title("2nd Tkinter window")
secondScreen.withdraw()
```

Above code have something like this to define the windows that you are using

Comment: shouldn't be using more than one instance of `Tk()`, for additional windows You should use `Toplevel`

Comment: What the case where the windows are not of the same dimensions?

Comment: Thanks guys. I finally got the solution: https://github.com/iamcodefoxx/Switch-Frames-Template/blob/master/switch_frames_template.py